# Why i can't start a django project use uwsgi after update the code

Tags: django, uwsgi

I met a problem, i can't start my django project use uwgsi after update the code. I can use before. I try django runserver to start, actually, that's work. but just can't use uwgsi.

Here is my uwsgi config.

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /var/myblog

module          = mysite.wsgi

home            = /root/venv_myblog/

master          = true

processes       = 10

socket          = 127.0.0.1:8001

vacuum          = true

pidfile=uwsgi.pid
```

Here is the problem:

```
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/root/venv_myblog/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./webapp/urls.py", line 15, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.views.opencv_tutorials'
```

But i can run it via runserver:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

February 01, 2019 - 08:44:19

Django version 2.1.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9000/

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Can't figure why！！！
Need help!!!!!!!
Please!!!!

Comment: if `opencv_tutorials` is view you should import it as `from webapp.views import opencv_tutorials` in `urls.py`

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari  Actually, I had. My code     from webapp.views.opencv_tutorials.opencv_tutorials import  *

Comment: webapp is folder, views.py is a file and opencv_tutorials is a function in views.py file right?

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari   webapp is folder, views is folder, opencv_tutorials is a python file, which contain functions

Comment: I can use runserver , it's ok, no problem!! but when i use uwsgi, it will raise exceptions.....

Comment: Are you able to hit URL after you run `python manage.py runserver` one more tip make sure you have empty __init__.py in webapp and views folders for imports

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari  Now, I have this problem "No module named 'web_app_cn.urls'" after i added a new app named web_app_cn....When i use python manage.py runserver command to launch, it can work. But with uwsgi, it can't ! Can't figure out......